# ¿Cómo puedo obtener un campo y luego pasarlo a otro archivo php?

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo que capturar una variable en un **input** para luego pasarla a un formulario de registro para que el usuario no tenga que estar repitiendo de nuevo su cédula, sino que ya venga capturada.

Este es parte del código donde debo capturar la variable

```html
<div class="form-floating">
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Cedula" id="cedula1" name="cedula" type="text" autocomplete="off" required />
  <label for="floatingPassword">cedula</label>
</div>

<script>
  public function () obtenerCedula {
    var ci = document.getElementById("cedula1");
    return = ci;
  }
</script>
```

Y aquí, una parte del código del otro formulario donde quiero que ya venga listo el campo:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="cedula" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Cedula</label>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cedula" name="cedula" value="" placeholder="Cedula" required />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Si estás ingresando los datos desde un html lo puedes pasar por Post. si es en un documento php a otro php investígate sobre las variables  $_SESSION, esto te podría ayudar

Answer (score 0):

Creo que está mal tu función en todos los aspectos.

Deberías hacer lo siguiente:

```js
return ci.value
```

Y deberías llamarlos de diferentes maneras para diferenciarlos, como `cedula1` y `cedula2`

Answer (score -2):

aun que analizando mas a fondo, si es un formulario flotante o desde otra pagina llamada por la principal, puedes llamar a el objeto window.opener para hacer referencia a la ventana que invoco a la ventana flotante desde javascript